# Google Merchant Feed Rules - Set identifier exists

Tags: google, shopify

I am trying to setup my first feed in Google Merchant.
I've got a feed from a website crawl on a Shopify store which has imported around 200 products.
Many products have issues due to missing GTIN so I've tried to create the following rule:

```
(If Website crawl.identifier exists [Autoselected] has no value) +1 condition ›
Set to: Website crawl.identifier exists "false"
```

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be doing anything.
I've tried multiple options in the Set to but can anyone tell me if what I've done is correct? I'm finding the instructions online very limited and difficult to follow.

Does the rule only work when it first loads frome the feed? Should I delete all the products and let the feed re-crawl or will they not re-import if deleted from within the Merchant page?

Any help would be really appreciated.